# Get hours between two times in moment.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, time, momentjs

I try like this :

```
let fromTime = '17:00'
let toTime = '20:00'
let a=[]
for(let i=parseInt(fromTime);i<parseInt(toTime);i++){
  a.push({time: i+':00'})
}
console.log(a)
```

It works. But It is the best way to do it?

Is the best way using moment js?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kinda, but you can get this result much better. first convert your time as moment.js `object` then get difference between `fromTime` and `toTime` then get diff as hours and finally add one hour for difference in loop.

```js
let fromTime = moment('17:00', 'HH:mm');
let toTime = moment('20:00', 'HH:mm');
let duration = moment.duration(toTime.diff(fromTime));
let diff = duration.hours();
let array = [];

for (i = 0; diff > i; i++) {
  let result = moment(fromTime).add(i, 'hours').format('HH:mm')
  array.push({
    result
  })
}

console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.2.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```

One thing, it make sense to get exact hours between `from` and `to` times, so you can set `i=1` to get only:

```
[
  {
    "result": "18:00"
  },
  {
    "result": "19:00"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of moment js i would recommend to use js-joda library.

```
import {LocalTime } from '@js-joda/core'

const start = LocalTime.parse("10:00")
const end = LocalTime.parse("20:30")

const times = [];

for (let time = start; time.compareTo(end) < 0; time = time.plusHours(1) ) {
  times.push(time.toString());
}

console.log(times);
```

https://js-joda.github.io/js-joda/manual/LocalTime.html